# Moving to OpenJDK (amazon-corretto) for Win 64-bit && 32-bit DLLs

Tags: java

We plan to move with our Java apps for Windows to amazon-corretto-8.202.08.2-windows-x64-jre (compiled on a Linux Jenkins server also with OpenJDK amazon-corretto-8.202.08.2-linux-x64). The problem is, that we have a bunch (100++) DLL connected to our Java classes, sometimes even from 3rd party. Is there some way to load 32-bit DLLs from the 64-bit JRE?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: There is not, because [WoW64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64) doesn't support that. You **can** run the 32-bit JRE with WoW64 (but that limits you to 4gb of RAM per JRE).